# "ERROR: sql.h not found" when installing ruby-odbc gem on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Attempting to install ruby-odbc gem on Debian/Ubuntu results in the following error;

`"ERROR: sql.h not found"`

Comment: Did you create a github issue for ruby-odbc?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Install the unixodbc-dev package, then try the gem install again

```
sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev
gem install ruby-odbc
```

Answer (score 44):

This happens on OSX too so brew to the rescue:

```
brew install unixodbc
```

Comment: To get this to work, I had to run `gem install ruby-odbc -- --with-odbc-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.2_1` (or whatever your path to ODBC dir as installed by Brew)

Comment: I also had to use the approach listed in the comment above by @dmichael to get it working. I'm on Yosemite.

Comment: same, here's the gem install command without weird formatting: gem install ruby-odbc -- --with-odbc-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.4

Comment: This worked for me: `gem install ruby-odbc -- --with-odbc-dir=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.9_1`

Answer (score 7):

On mac, the gem couldn't find the native package.

```
    brew install unixodbc
```

See the path where it is installed with:

```
    brew list unixodbc
```

And you'll get something like:

> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.11/.bottle/etc/ (2 files)
> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.11/bin/dltest
> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.11/bin/isql
> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.11/bin/iusql
> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.11/bin/odbc_config
> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.11/bin/odbcinst
> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.11/bin/slencheck
> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.11/include/unixODBC/ (2 files)
> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.11/include/ (11 files)
> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.11/lib/libodbc.2.dylib
> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.11/lib/libodbccr.2.dylib
> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.11/lib/libodbcinst.2.dylib
> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.11/lib/pkgconfig/ (3 files)
> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.11/lib/ (6 other files)
> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.11/share/man/ (8 files)

apply that output to

```
    gem install ruby-odbc -- --with-odbc-dir=[path to unixodbc]
```

Example:

> gem install ruby-odbc -- --with-odbc-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.11

Answer (score -3):

This answer worked for me, thanks to @tombeynon very much. It is also simpler than the previous and could be implemented in a docker container.

```
apt-get install unixodbc-dev
gem install odbc_adapter
```

Comment: This answer is not a useful answer. The question has already been solved, and the only difference between yours and theirs is that you removed `sudo` and installed a different package. A comment on their answer like "For docker containers, remember to remove sudo and `gem install odbc_adapter` instead" would have been more suitable