# How to install ruby-odbc gem on M1 Mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am trying to get a rails project running on an M1 mac.
I have to use ruby 2.6.2 and rails 5.2.3

I am using rbenv 1.1.2 and homebrew 3.0

When I run `bundle install`, I get this error

```
An error occurred while installing ruby-odbc (0.99999), and Bundler cannot continue.
  Make sure that `gem install ruby-odbc -v '0.99999'` succeeds before bundling.
```

So then I run `gem install ruby-odbc -v '0.99999'`

This leads to another error

```
ERROR:  Error installing ruby-odbc:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /Users/david.lee/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/ruby- 
odbc-0.99999/ext
/Users/david.lee/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/bin/ruby -I 
/Users/david.lee/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20210208-46271-1tguvxe.rb 
extconf.rb
checking for version.h... no
checking for sql.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/david.lee/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-odbc-dir
    --without-odbc-dir
    --with-odbc-include
    --without-odbc-include=${odbc-dir}/include
    --with-odbc-lib
    --without-odbc-lib=${odbc-dir}/lib
ERROR: sql.h not found

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Users/david.lee/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/-darwin-20/2.6.0/ruby-odbc-0.99999/mkmf.log
```

When I stackoverflow this error, I get this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17068590/error-sql-h-not-found-when-installing-ruby-odbc-gem-on-ubuntu) which tells me to `brew install unixodbc`, so I do that and try to `bundle install` again, which gives me the same error.

All the stackoverflow posts related to sql.h files not being installed do not solve my issue.

**HOW DO I INSTALL THIS GEM?**

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to a co-worker, I got this resolved.
You need to install the gem while pointing it to the unixodbc directory

This was the line that installed it for me

`gem install ruby-odbc -- --with-odbc-dir=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.9`

To find your unixodbc path, run `brew info unixodbc`

That will give you the path and your version number of unixodbc. Then you put the path and version number in the appropriate spot
`gem install ruby-odbc -- --with-odbc-dir=put your path and version number of unixodbc here`

Comment: `gem install ruby-odbc -- --with-odbc-dir=$(brew --prefix unixodbc)` will work for an arbitrary version of `unixodbc`

Answer (score 2):

None of the above solutions worked for me when I had this error. This is what worked for me:

```
bundle config set build.ruby-odbc --with-odbc-dir=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.11
```

Per this StackOverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69047546/error-sql-h-not-found-when-installing-ruby-odbc-gem-with-apple-m1-homebrew)

Answer (score 1):

If you need this to work while running the `bundle` command, do the following:

```
bundle config build.odbc --with-odbc-dir=$(brew --prefix unixodbc)
```

Comment: Just a short note that this should say `build.ruby-odbc`, but otherwise worked well for me and has the benefit that you don't have to go searching for the exact path in brew.