# "ERROR: sql.h not found" when installing ruby-odbc gem with Apple M1 homebrew

Tags: ruby, rubygems, homebrew

Context: on Apple M1, homebrew's location is `/opt/homebrew' (not the usual` /usr/local`)

```
macOS Intel: /usr/local
macOS ARM: /opt/homebrew
```

When I install ruby-odbc gem I'm getting the error `ERROR: sql.h not found`

If I pass in commandline arguments, I can get it to install...
`gem install ruby-odbc -- --with-odbc-dir=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.9_1/`

However, we are using bundler. I don't remember the best way to put this into a Gemfile and I'm convinced there must be a better way to solve this.

How do I tell gem, bundler, or my macOS that it should look in /opt/homebrew when compiling ruby-odbc?

I see that ruby-odbc uses mkmf.rb's have_header in core ruby. Perhaps a newer ruby would work too?

Answer (score 5):

`bundle config set build.ruby-odbc --with-odbc-dir=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.9_1`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Awesome! works!!!!